# How to delete multiple checked items in a ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, checkbox

```
protected void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    for (int i = 0; i < listview1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        ListViewDataItem items = listview1.Items[i];
        CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)items.FindControl("chkdel");

        if (chkBox.Checked == true)
        {
            if (Session["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                dt = (DataTable)Session["CurrentTable"];
                dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

    Session["CurrentTable"] = dt;
    listview1.DataSource = dt;
    listview1.DataBind();
    BindDataToGridviewDropdownlist();     
}
```

Here it is deleting one row only. How to delete multiple checked items in listview?

Comment: You're not adjusting your index after removing an item.

Comment: Why do you get the DataTable dt always from Session dt = (DataTable)Session["CurrentTable"];

Comment: In loading time i want to show empty rows thats why i took session

Comment: Can u tell me how to adjust my index  – Grant Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me .....

```
protected void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            if (Session["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                dt = (DataTable)Session["CurrentTable"];
                int j = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < listview1.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    ListViewDataItem items = listview1.Items[i];
                    CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)items.FindControl("chkdel");

                    if (chkBox.Checked == true)
                    {
                        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(j);
                        dt.AcceptChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                Session["CurrentTable"] = dt;
                listview1.DataSource = dt;
                listview1.DataBind();
                BindDataToGridviewDropdownlist();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Hans Derks above in comment, you are taking data table from session each time but not actually updating it using `Session["CurrentTable"]=dt;` like:

```
protected void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    for (int i = 0; i < listview1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        ListViewDataItem items = listview1.Items[i];
        CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)items.FindControl("chkdel");

        if (chkBox.Checked == true)
        {
            if (Session["CurrentTable"] != null)
            {
                dt = (DataTable)Session["CurrentTable"];
                dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                Session["CurrentTable"]=dt;
                listview1.DataSource = dt;
                listview1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }

    BindDataToGridviewDropdownlist();     
}
```

Comment: This answer is not deleting the multiple checked rows

Comment: dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i); There is no row at position 3(Indexoutofrange)

Comment: Oh, I removed values from session datatable but not from listview. so count is more for listview thus `Indexoutofrange` error. Also need to remove it from listview

Comment: ya ...can u suggest me Plz ..Improve your answer

Comment: @Kailas,updated answer, moved listview update code inside loop

Comment: Here when i select multiple check boxes its not showing error ..and even though it is deleting single row even i select 3 check boxes

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ...finally i got it

Answer (score 0):

Refactored version of Pranav's answer:

```
protected void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the Table from the session.
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["CurrentTable"];
    // Only actually proceed, if we have a value.
    if(dt != null)
    {
        // Loop through each item.
        for (int i = 0; i < listview1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            // Find the checkbox to determine if it's checked.
            ListViewDataItem items = listview1.Items[i];
            CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)items.FindControl("chkdel");
            if (chkBox.Checked == true)
            {
                // Remove the row at the current index.
                dt.rows.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        // Update the session and rebind the data.
        Session["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        listview1.DataSource = dt;
        listview1.DataBind();
        BindDataToGridviewDropdownlist(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Same error dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i); There is no row at position 3(Indexoutofrange)

Comment: for this when i select single check box it is deleting but when i select 2 check box ....it is showing error

Comment: Ah gotcha - I've just corrected my answer as the count is 1 based, whereas the Items array is 0 based.

Comment: Here it is deleting 2 rows on 3 row selection

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the if(chkBox...) statement, how many times does it hit? Also, if I recall correctly, you should be able to get the instance of the datasource from the listview, which will almost guarantee you have the same version, instead of a possibly out of sync'd version from the session.

Comment: and i got another issue with this on checked row is not deleting ..when i select 2 rows one row is deleting ..on 3 selection 2 deleting ...on 4 selection its getting error

Comment: when i select one checkbox the control is not going in side the if(chkbox.checked==true)

Comment: when i select 2 checkbox the control is going third time after 2 times it skiped

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ...finally i got it